Mathematical form of Recurrent Neural Networks with control input and feature vector
Assume that we have a feature vector $x$, control input vector $u$ and output vector $y$.
If we use RNNs (Recurrent Neural Networks), what will be the general mathematical equations
for such a system?

what you mean by "control input vector"? (or equivalently, what's the difference from a feature vector)
